# Does pandas.Series.unique() preserve order?

Tags: python, pandas

Simple question I haven't been able to find an answer to yet:

Given a pandas Series, I *think* the order of values given by Series.unique() is that in which they are first encountered in the series, and *not* any sort sorted order. I.e.

```
from pandas import Series
s = Series(['b','b','b','a','a','b'])

s.unique()
>>> array(['b', 'a'], dtype=object)
```

This is the behavior I want for my application, but can someone tell me if I'm guaranteed to get this order? The documentation is not clear.

Comment: note that np.unique does NOT preserve order

Comment: Yep...that caused some frustrating issues early, hence attempting this method instead.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

yes this generally holds true. pandas objects have ordered indices and the rows will not reshuffle until you tell them to do so...

Comment: True, but the output of Series.unique() is standard numpy array, so it's not necessarily true that this would hold in this case, is it? Just want a definitive answer before I implement.

Comment: no, ``Series.unique`` is NOT just calling ``np.unique`` that's the point.

Comment: this is why pandas has been created!. Pandas is about ordered data. It has a column order and an index order and it's order will always be respected until you tell the object to reshuffle in any way. It's so idiomatic for pandas that it isn't even explicitly mentioned in the doc I guess, because thats the whole point.

Answer (score 17):

As of now, the pandas documentation contains this line: [Uniques are returned in order of appearance, this does NOT sort.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html)

Comment: So this implies that if a series is already ordered when calling unique, that the unique values are also sorted.